# get response for particular asihttprequest

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, asihttprequest

My problem is as follows:-I have multiple asihttprequests and even i dont know how many, its like dynamic, at program runs I have 1 latlongarray for latitude-logitude which comes from webservice so i dont know how many latitudes longitudes  are there.Then I will execute asihttprequest for getting distance from user location to all objects in latlongarray.So how can I recognize which request finished at method didfinishresponse for asihttprequest  :-

```
   for(int i=0,i<[latlongarray count],i++)
   if (![self queue]) {
      [self setQueue:[[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease]];
   }


   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url for getting distance"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
   [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
   [[self queue] addOperation:request]; //queue is an NSOperationQueue


- (void)requestDone:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   //I NEED TO DO SOMTHING HERE.
}
```

i already get distance with some 5 or 6 static asihttprequest but in this case i need to do somthing dynamically.how can i do this?

and thanx for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store information in the 'userInfo' field in the request when you create it, which you can then use in requestDone:

```
request.userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value", @"key", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assign `tag` to request using an integer value. in requestDone, you can get back the value.

> request.tag = 1;